# setting ack to client results in duplicate message delivery stomp

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, stomp, activemq-artemis, sockjs

I have a stomp application and I set the `ack` mode to `client` during subscription from front-end. During the subscription the same client during a session would connect to the same queue in the message broker ActiveMQ Artemis because a session id is used for queue.But a different id is passed in the header every time the user reloads the page.

The subscription code is shown below.

```
            consumer.subscribe(
                '/queue.'+ rscSessionId,
                function (response) {
                    console.log("resposne");
                },
                {
                    "subscription-type": "ANYCAST",
                    ack: "client",
                    id: generateId(),
                }
            );
```

Once I send message from client it gets send to frontend with following headers.

```
MESSAGE
subscription:1234
message-id:1543449
destination:/queue.sessionid
expires:1653914606725
redelivered:false
priority:4
persistent:true
timestamp:1653912806717
destination-type:ANYCAST
__AMQ_CID:30e64793-dd9b-11ec-8843-c238460c3152
_type:ResponseData
content-length:300
```

and afterwards on every reload.

```
MESSAGE
subscription:1235
message-id:1543449
destination:/queue.sessionid
expires:1653914606725
redelivered:true
priority:4
persistent:true
timestamp:1653912806717
destination-type:ANYCAST
__AMQ_CID:30e64793-dd9b-11ec-8843-c238460c3152
_type:ResponseData
content-length:300
```

You can see that `redelivered` is set to `true` after first delivery and after that every response has `redelivered` to `false`. the `subscription` value keeps getting changed though because of the `id` passed in header.

How can I make it deliver only once but with guarantee?

Comment: @JustinBertram I was thinking the same,looks like stomp documentation specifies about acknowledging messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually acknowledging the message once you receive it? If you don't acknowledge the message then once the client closes the connection and subscribes again it will receive the same message again. The different value you're seeing for the `subscription` header indicates this is what is happening.

To be clear, if you're using the `client` acknowledgement mode then once you receive the `MESSAGE` frame you need to send a corresponding [`ACK`](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#ACK) frame in order to acknowledge the message. Your client should have a way to do this since it is a standard part of the STOMP specification.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that Artemis is configured with publisher/subscriber messaging style. In this case, every new consumer/receiver/client will get the messages aka you write/read from a topic.

Changing to a point-to-point message style would fix the issue (would only be read once) aka a queue.

This is usually decided by the setup but I recall that ActiveMQ allowed producer to create those on the fly.

If you do need a topic, then you will have to handle the IDs on the client side.

Comment: The configuration is already set to `anycast` for activemq artemis making it point to point , also the subscription from frontend is also for `anycast`.

Comment: @pacman Can you see if the message is ACKed from the queue before refresh?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: The client is already using point-to-point semantics because it's setting the `subscription-type` header as `ANYCAST` when it subscribes.

Comment: You should have access to some management console https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management-console.html